# I want only get the id when filter in angular

Tags: angular, api, categories

this my filter in service.components.ts

```
this.pijatService
        .getById(this.id)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe((x: any) => {
          this.form.patchValue(x);
          console.log(x);
          this.form.value.nomor_telepon = x.telepon.nomor_telepon;
          var tempD = x.categories;
          this.form.value.category_id = tempD.filter(
            (data: any) => data.pivot.service_id == this.id
          );
        });
```

result

```
categories: Array(2)[
0: {id: 1, name: 'Bayi', slug: 'bayi', created_at: '2021-12-31T08:34:36.000000Z', updated_at: '2021-12-31T08:34:36.000000Z', …}
1: {id: 2, name: 'Capek', slug: 'capek', created_at: '2021-12-31T08:34:36.000000Z', updated_at: '2021-12-31T08:34:36.000000Z', …}
length: 2]
```

i want final result like this

```
categories: Array(2)[1,2]
```

i try to change the filter but its just got me error

another try from answer:
`let selectedList = x.categories.map((elem: any) => ({ id: elem.id }));`

it give me result

```
0: {id: 1}
1: {id: 2}
length: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop other properties this way:

```
tempD.map(({ id, ...dropAttrs }) => id);
```

Comment: i try but the id for categories ist not define inside subscribe

Comment: well, do it on the array which returns the value.

Comment: tempD.map(({ tempD.id, ...dropAttrs }) => id);

Comment: tempD.map(({ id, ...dropAttrs }) => id);

Comment: did it work? @Skipzenni

Comment: yeah i did to categories and it gave me red line on "id"

Comment: ok I will edit the answer.

Comment: oh no, changed but if i save it, console will give me error 
error TS7031: Binding element 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.

101           tempD.map(({ id, ...dropAttrs }) => id); 

i try to give any or try to make property id on top but still error same,

Comment: well give the id the type of any where you bind it

Comment: i already did on top, subscribe and inside map too, still doest correct the id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```ts
let selectedList = categories.map((elem: any) => elem.id);
```